# Docker - server hitting EOF

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I just installed docker and boot2docker on Mavericks. I did the usual

```
boot2docker init
boot2docker start
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4243
```

and it says the server is up and running. But when I try to connect (e.g. `docker info`) I get

```
2014/06/07 10:45:55 Get http://localhost:4243/v1.11/info: EOF
```

I'm guessing something is wrong with the daemon but I can't crack this one... Does anyone know what it could be?

Note: I didn't install the bundled copy of VirtualBox when I installed docker/boot2docker because I already had it installed. Could there be something missing from that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/tag/v0.12.0

> Note: this update changes the exposed Docker port from 4243 to 2375,
>   and will require the v0.12.0 version of the new boot2docker management tool.
>   This Boot2Docker release is not backwards compatible with older management tools

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but couldn't really use boot2docker v0.12.0 yet.

I just install `boot2docker` using Go directly `go get github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli`